# Setting routing for 2 different action methods with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to call 2 action methods, one to show the delete screen and the second to actually delete the data. Below are my action methods.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewBankHoliday(DateTime? holidayDate = null, string countryID = null)
{
    //something
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewBankHoliday(BankHolidayViewModel viewModel)
{
    //something
}
```

My `route.config` is below. My first route works fine which takes me to the delete view but the confirm delete route throws an error.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Operations/DeleteBankHoliday.aspx",
            new { Controller = "BankHoliday", action = "NewBankHoliday"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
             null,
             "{holidayDate}/{countryID}",
             new { Controller = "BankHoliday", action = "NewBankHoliday" }
        );
```

Error message:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: what is the error thrown? Please also add that to your question for more clarification.

Comment: You second route is not making sense. And the method to delete is a POST method so it does not have a route definition. But you have not shown a method for deleting anything so unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: How can I add a route for Post.

Comment: You don't. You submit a form. But the names of your methods do not make sense. You have a `BankHolidayController` so the methods should be (say) `Details()` to display the details of the holliday, `Create()` to create a new one, `Edit()` to edit the details and `Delete()` to delete one (and perhaps `Index()` to display a list of all holidays)

Comment: Alright, but thats good but can I have 2 routes

Comment: 2 routes for what? Routes are to GET methods. Its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: So you mean I cannot use Routes to POST?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115674/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-maxspan).